# SQL Server 2005 : how to implement limit x,y without using ORDER BY?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table where is no numeric column which can be used in `order by`.

Can someone help to adapt existing queries to my situation?

I need to get only 4 columns from the table (let's call them `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`). I'm trying to do that within two last hours, but with no success ;(

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table where is no any numeric field which can be used in
>   `order by`

It don't necessarily have to be a numeric column. Whatever the column you want to sort on, include that in `order by` clause and make sure the column is having an index.

```
select field1,field2,field3,field4
from tbl1
order by field1;
```